# Enable Core dumps for C++ app (called via apache -> Perl -> C++)

Tags: c++, linux, apache, perl, coredump

I have a web GUI which provides ON/OFF control of a C++ application. The C++ app is called from a perl wrapper who's job it is to keep the program running and restart it if it has stopped.

Clicking the web page button (ultimately) launches `startWrapper.pl` *in the background*.

The problem is the C++ app crashes with segfault once every few days.  I'd like enable core dumps for this background task.

However, everything I've read seems to require a tty and/or login session (eg. ulimit command).

How would I enable core dumps for this background task?  Possible to set the configuration from within the C++ source code?  Linux config file?

As pseudo code, `startWrapper.pl` (briefly) looks like:

```
if (is_process_running() )
{
    return;
}
else
{
    while (1)
    {
        system("/path/to/c++/application &");

        while (1)
        {
            if (not_running_anymore())
                 break;
            sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I clicked the answer too soon. Using `setrlimit` works if I a) call the binary directly or b) call it from the perl wrapper.  But if the perl wrapper is called from apache it doesn't dump the core.  (I put a "bomb" in the program to segfault after 10s.  When called from apache, the wrapper detected it and restarted the binary but no core file.)

Could this be some user ID vs effective ID issue?

Apache starts the perl wrapper as *apache*. The perl wrapper uses `system` to launch the binary which is setuid root.

**EDIT II**

**Started Manually**

```
2016-08-17 13:50:35 : DvStorStartASIRecord.pl starting
2016-08-17 13:50:35 : DvStorStartASIRecord.pl: Starting DvASIRecord 0 0
2016-08-17 13:50:35 : DvASIRecord Current Dir: '/usr/local/dvstor/bin'
2016-08-17 13:50:35 : DvASIRecord Core Limits - Cur: 18446744073709551615 Max: 18446744073709551615
2016-08-17 13:50:35 : DvASIRecord: ASI recording started 0 0
2016-08-17 13:50:46 : DvStorStartASIRecord: DvASIRecord terminated unexpectedly. Restarting
```

**Started via apache**

```
2016-08-17 13:50:59 : DvStorOperation.cgi::startRecord() from 192.168.2.10
2016-08-17 13:50:59 : DvStorStartASIRecord.pl starting
2016-08-17 13:50:59 : DvStorStartASIRecord.pl: Starting DvASIRecord 0 0
2016-08-17 13:50:59 : DvASIRecord Current Dir: '/usr/local/dvstor/cgi-bin'
2016-08-17 13:50:59 : DvASIRecord Core Limits - Cur: 18446744073709551615 Max: 18446744073709551615
2016-08-17 13:50:59 : DvASIRecord: ASI recording started 0 0
2016-08-17 13:51:09 : DvStorStartASIRecord: DvASIRecord terminated unexpectedly. Restarting
```

**EDIT III**

ps listing of related processes

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1 S root      1999     1  0  80   0 -  7525 poll_s Aug16 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2023  1999  0  80   0 -  7721 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2024  1999  0  80   0 -  7721 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2025  1999  0  80   0 -  7719 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2026  1999  0  80   0 -  7719 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2027  1999  0  80   0 -  7719 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2028  1999  0  80   0 -  7721 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2029  1999  0  80   0 -  7721 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache    2030  1999  0  80   0 -  7721 inet_c Aug16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
5 S apache   27793  1999  0  80   0 -  7719 inet_c 09:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
0 S apache   29436     1  0  80   0 -  1315 hrtime 09:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/dvstor/bin/DvStorStartASIRecord.pl tsNum=0
4 S root     29573     1  3 -40   - - 26599 hrtime 09:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/dvstor/bin/DvASIRecord 0 2
```

Comment: It is C++ related if there is a way to enable core dumps from within the C++ code, eg. if there is some sysctl, ioctl, etc API that would enable for this binary only.

Comment: Actually no idea why this doesn't work with Apache. Maybe Apache sets for some reasons hard limits which can't be risen by your child process. To investigate this I'd call getrlimit to check soft and hard limits while running from perl wrapper and then from Apache.
I also suggests checking for error code from setrlimit.

Comment: Checking the limits, both 'cur' and 'max' are the same whether starting manually or via apache.  See the logs above.  The only difference seems to be the current working directory (as reported by get_current_dir_name()).  [and no core dumps in there either].  Could apache re-direct the location of the core files to somewhere else?

Comment: That's the point! Core is dumped to current working directory. Your process (user running your application) doesn't have permission to write to the current working directory. Simply change current working directory at the beginning of your application to the one where you have permission to write. Try `chdir("/tmp")` just before `setrlimit` for example.

Comment: No joy.  The binary is running setuid root so figured it could write anywhere.  But tried chdir /tmp but same behavior.  I've included the process listing with  PID/PPID in case that's helpful.  This doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a possibility to set system limits from C++ code.
Look at `getrlimit`, `setrlimit` functions.

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

rlimit limitValue;
limitValue.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
limitValue.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;

setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &limitValue);
```

`RLIMIT_CORE` stands for core size
`RLIM_INFINITY` - unlimited
`rlim_cur` - soft limit
`rlim_max` - hard limit